# Why isn't PHP reading my $_POST data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following functions in JavaScript:

```
function AddTextBox(id) {
    if (id == 'national age gender' || id == 'arizona age gender') {
    document.getElementById('text_boxes').innerHTML='Age Group: <input name="age_gender" id="age_group" type="text"> <br /> Male population: <input name="age_gender" id="male" type="text"> Female population: <input name="age_gender" id="female" type="text"> <br /> Male %: <input name="age_gender" id="male_percent" type="text">  Female %: <input name="age_gender" id="female_percent" type="text"> <br /> Males per 100 females <input name="age_gender" id="m_per_100_f" type="text"> <br /> <button onclick="validateAgeGender(id);">Add</button>'; 

    }
    if (id == 'national race' || id == 'arizona race') {
    document.getElementById('text_boxes').innerHTML='Category: <input id="cat" type="text"> <br /> White population: <input name="race" id="white" type="text"> White %: <input name="race" id="white percent" type="text"> <br /> Black population: <input name="race" id="black" type="text"> Black %: <input name="race" id="black_percent" type="text"> <br /> Native American population: <input name="race" id="native_american" type="text"> Native American %: <input name="race" id="native_american_percent" type="text"> <br /> Asian: <input name="race" id="asian" type="text"> Asian %: <input name="race" id="asian_percent" type="text"> <br /> Pacific Islander: <input name="race" id="pacific_islander" type="text"> Pacific Islander %: <input name="race" id="pacific_islander_percent" type="text"> <br /> Other: <input name="race" id="other" type="text"> Other %: <input name="race" id="other_percent" type="text"> <br /> <button onclick="validateRace(id);">Add</button>';

    }

}



function validateAgeGender(id) {
    if (id == 'national age gender') {
        var data = $('#age_gender').serialize();
        $.post('/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalAgeGender.php', data);
    }
    if (id == 'arizona age gender') {
        var data = $('#age_gender').serialize();
        $.post('/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/ArizonaAgeGender.php', data);
    }
}
```

And I have the following PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['age_gender'])) { 
    $formSerialized = $_POST['age_gender'];
    $formData = array();
    parse_str($formSerialized, $formData);
    addRow($formData, $link); 
}

function addRow($dataArray, $link) {
    $age_group = $dataArray[0];
    $populations = array(intval($dataArray[1]) + intval($dataArray[2]), intval($dataArray[1]), intval($dataArray[2]));
    $percents = array(doubleval($dataArray[3]) + doubleval($dataArray[4]), doubleval($dataArray[3]), doubleval($dataArray[4]));
    $m_per_100_f = doubleval($dataArray[6]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO national_age_gender_demographics (age_group, both_pop, male_pop, female_pop, both_percent, male_percent, female_percent, males_per_100_females)
    VALUES ('$age_group','$populations[0]','$populations[1]','$populations[2]','$percents[0]','$percents[1]','$percents[2]','$m_per_100_f')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $query . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );

}
```

Could anyone tell me why this isn't working?  I would like to be able to add to the table by the user data.

Comment: show us your form data.

Comment: Please, use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Casting to int or whatever is not a general purpose strategy. You will make a mistake, and it could cost you huge.

Comment: use `print_r($_POST);` for see all post value in php and use `console.log();` for see value of variable in JavaScript we must know form data and $_POST value

Comment: After the line $query = "INSERT INTO ... ". echo $query; & paste here. What error do you get?

Comment: because you never pass `age_gender` to the server, if you did `$.post('url', {age_gender : data}`, this would work

Comment: # is ID you have NAME name="age_gender" id="age_group"

Comment: Mplungjan - that was the issue.  Now I need to figure out how to deserialize the string properly.  Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `mysqli`, then change `mysql_error()`  to `mysqli_error()` for finding the problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems,you have not set proper name attribute to form input fields,you have just used   different id attributes but same name attributes for input fields.

As Jquery serialize use form elements name attributes and value to encode form elements data as a string (name=value)for submission.

correct me if i am wrong??.